# Viewing available message strings (from mc.exe) in a 3rd party DLL

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, resources, message, event-log

Is there a way to view all the messages (ie messages created for FormatMessage by the mc.exe message compiler) available within a DLL?  It appears they are added as a single resource as type 11.  Unfortunately that resource is binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) for all things resource-related.  These messages show up as a "Message Table" resource that contains all the human-readable strings and their IDs.

Comment: For some reason Resource Hacker showed all the resources except the message table. But the author linked to an open source alternative that DOES show the message table: http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindResource` or `FindResourceEx` to enum all resources in the DLL. Then you can use `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY`, `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA` and `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK` to decode the data. See for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/msgdump.aspx for details or serch for other examples searching for the API functions and the sutructures.